# How I can soft-reboot my wifi modem from linux command line?

Tags: networking, lan, wifi-configuration

I am trying to create a shortcut to reboot my wifi modem without opening wifi configuration page 192.168.1.1 in browser, directly from linux terminal command line.

I tried telnet, I don't see any command for reboot or restart.

````
$ telnet 192.168.1.1
Connected to 192.168.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.

Password: ****************
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2017 Binatone Telecommunication Pvt Ltd
DT850W> reboot
Valid commands are:
sys             exit            ether           wan
etherdbg        tcephydbg       ip              ip6
bridge          dot1q           pktqos          show
set             lan
DT850W>```

``` DT850W>
DT850W> sys
adjtime         countrycode     edit            feature
hostname        log             resetlog        stdio
time            syslog          version         view
wdog            romreset        infohide        upnp
atsh            wificalcheckflagdiag            routeip
bridge          save            display         password
default         adminname       modelcheck      multiuser
defaultTCrestorepswauthen       hangdbg         ledtr68
pppnamelock     defaultpwdcheck fwuptimeout     autocwmpoui
sptromsize      compileid       dhcpprobe       dhcpfor2ndusr
dvlan           pswconfirmflag  fortr69flag     hiddenaclrulefla
cwmp            socket          filter          ddns
cpu             snmp
DT850W>  ```
````

Comment: Is reboot/restart a parameter of the `sys` command, maybe?

Comment: If there is a way to do it via telnet, then the manual should have a description of how. I really do not see a reason why they would have left it out.

Comment: @StarCat sys gave me above options.

Comment: You might be able to access the appropriate URLs on the modem’s web interface by using the right `curl` or `wget` commands from the command line. You probably first have to find out how to authenticate, then access the URL that sets off a modem reboot and possibly another URL if there’s a confirmation screen.

Answer (score 0):

Binatone doesn't provide CLI manuals for some reason, but this should work: `set reboot`

Comment: ```sys reboot``` I was able to do this with : ```(sleep 3;echo admin;sleep 3;echo password;sleep 3;echo sys reboot;sleep 3;) | telnet 192.168.1.1``` Takes 5-10 seconds.